# Ruby : Remove something between [] of a string with a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I got thoses 2 strings :

```
[ Nope ] I need that

I need this
```

And I want to have only 'I need that' & 'I need this'

So I tried regex like that :

```
[ Nope ] (.+)$|(.+)
```

By the way, this doesn't work but

```
[ Nope ] (.+)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string = '[ Nope ] I need that'
string.gsub(/\[(.*)\]/, '').strip
# => "I need that"
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use this pattern with sub or gsub method:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

details:

`[^\]]` is a character class that contains all characters except ]